# Django: Passing object from template to views

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to use the same template to view information about each of my database objects. I would like to be able to click on each element in the list and have it link me to a page with info about it. I'm thinking there's an easier way than making a view for each unique object.

I'm listing all of my database objects on my list.html like this:

```
{% for instance in object_info %}
    <li><a href="object">{{ instance.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

My views.py has this view:

```
def object_view(request):
    data = Object.objects.filter(name="")
    context={
    'object_info':data
    }
    return render(request, "object.html", context)
```

Can I pass each `{{ instance.name }}` to the view and use that as a variable for my filter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay first off never do this:

```
data = Object.objects.filter(name="")
```

Django has an `all()` function that will return all objects:

```
data = Object.objects.all()
```

Secondly, I hope `object_view`, `data`, `object_info`, `object.html` are not your actual variable names! If so, please make sure they are meaningful to your application.

Okay back to your problem. Well, you don't need to make a view for every single object. I am assuming that `<a href="object">...</a>` should refer to a new page that will be populated with the selected object.

If so, you would want to have urls in the `<a>` tags like this: `/objects/object_id/`.

This new url needs to be defined like this in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^objects/(?P<oid>[0-9]+)/$', views.object_specific_view, name='objects'),
]
```

Note the `oid` url argument. We will be using it to access our specific object.

Now your original template, `list.html`, should look like:

```
    {% for instance in object_info %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'objects' oid = instance.id %}">instance.name</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Where we supply `instance.id` to `oid` url argument to produce something like `objects/1/` or `objects/2/` etc.

Now, this means that you will only need to create one more view with another template.

Your second view `object_specific_view`:

```
def object_specific_view(request, oid): # The url argument oid is automatically supplied by Django as we defined it carefully in our urls.py
    object = Object.objects.filter(id=oid).first()
    context={
      'object':object
    }
    return render(request, "specific_object.html", context)
```

Now you just need to design your `specific_object.html` and access the `object` instance to show details of a specific object :).